# django join query

Tags: python, django

Im new to django. I have this model, In tblperson, only the forgein keys of type and status are saved. How do I join all tables to display their value not their forgein key? For example.

```
TblPerson.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM "Tblperson" INNER JOIN "Tblstatus" ON ("TblPerson"."Status" = "Tblstatus"."ID")'):
```

Thanks.

```
class TblPerson(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column=u'ID') 
    Type = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column=u'Type', blank=True)
    Status = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column=u'Status', blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'tblPerson'

class Tblstatus(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column=u'statStatusID')
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=25, db_column=u'statStatus', blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'tblStatus'

class Tbltype(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column=u'typTypeID')
    Type = models.CharField(max_length=25, db_column=u'typType', blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'tblType'
```

Answer (score 1):

The power of Django is in the [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), which means you should be writing very little SQL if at all.

```
   class Person(models.Model):
        #don't use this because id is generated automatically
        #ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column=u'ID')            

        type = models.ForeignKey(Type)
        status = models.ForeignKey(Status)


    #Type,Status analogous

    #filter like this
    selected = Person.objects.filter(type=SomeType)
    for p in selected:
        print p.id,p.type,p.status
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to re-write your models. So, that your TblPerson has a many to one relationship with Tblstatus

```
class TblPerson(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column=u'ID') 
    Type = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column=u'Type', blank=True)
    Status = models.ForeignKey(Tblstatus, null=True, db_column=u'Status', blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'tblPerson'

class Tblstatus(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column=u'statStatusID')
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=25, db_column=u'statStatus', blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'tblStatus'
```

Using this you would be able to query for TblPerson objects for which Tblstatus exists like this

```
TblPerson.objects.filter(Status__isnull=False)
```